# Referring another model's method from current model's view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I'm pretty new to Rails.

I'm working on an app where you can upload a csv file or create a manual bank transaction. Previously I had both the manual entry and uploaded csv file entries in a single table called Transaction. Now I'm trying to store the uploaded file entries in a separate table called Bank.
So I have a Bank model and a Transaction model and their respective controllers & views.

Previously I had "New Transaction" form and "Upload CSV" form in the same page called "New Transaction" to avoid creating separate views for both and it was working fine.
Now, After I've created a new model(Bank) for CSV uploaded entries, I tried to refer the Bank model's import method path from my "New Transaction" page to import csv files. But its returning me a Load Error.

```
LoadError in BanksController#new
Unable to autoload constant BanksController, expected /app/controllers/banks_controller.rb to define it
```

This is my Bank Model:

```
class Bank < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :admin
    paginates_per 10

    def self.to_csv(options = {})
      CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
        csv << column_names
        all.each do |transaction|
          csv << transaction.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
        end
      end
    end

    extend ActiveModel::Model
    include ActiveModel::Validations
    include ActiveModel::Conversion
    attr_accessor :file

    validates :date, presence: true
    validates :notes, presence: true
    validates :t_type, presence: true
    validates :t_method, presence: true
    validates :amount, presence: true
    validates :paid_by, presence: true
    validates :paid_to, presence: true
    #validates :cashbox, presence: true
    validates :bank, presence: true

    def self.import(file)
        CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
            transaction_hash = row.to_hash
            t = Bank.new(transaction_hash.except("cashbox"))
            t.id = Bank.maximum(:id).next
            t.save!
        end
    end    
end
```

This is my Bank Controller:

```
class BankController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_admin!

    def index
        @banks = Bank.all.order('created_at DESC')
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.csv { send_data @banks.to_csv }
        end
    end

    def import
        begin
            Bank.import(params[:file])
            redirect_to root_url, notice: "Transactions Imported!"
        rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => exception
            redirect_to :back, alert: "#{exception.message}"
        end
    end

    def editview
        @q = Transaction.ransack(params[:q])
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.csv { send_data @transactions_list_for_csv.to_csv, filename: 'transactions.csv' }
        end
    end
end
```

This is my New Transaction View from transaction model where it contains both forms for new transaction and upload csv:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="container new-container">
        <h3>New Transaction</h3>
        <%= render 'form' %> </br>
        <%= link_to "Back", root_path %>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="divider"></div>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="import-col">
        <h3>Import a CSV File:</h3>
        <%#= form_tag import_transactions_path, multipart: true do %>
        <%= form_tag import_banks_path, multipart: true do %>
            <%= file_field_tag :file, class: "form-control", required: true %></br>
            <%= submit_tag "Import CSV", class: "btn btn-success" %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is Transactions controllers new method:

```
def new 
        @transaction = Transaction.new
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controllers are supposed to be named in plural. Rename it to `BanksController`